# Group by with WIndows Function- Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I know, there is no point using Group by here. But I was experimenting something & getting an error saying column cost should be in group by or used in an aggregate function. I want to understand what's going on internally and why the logic is incorrect. Let's say I have a table :

```
name | date | category | cost,   
jill  | 2019-04-01 | pen | 10 , 
jill  | 2019-04-01 | pen | 40 , 
jill  | 2019-04-01 | coat | 20 , 
Farida | 2019-03-01 | coat | 25,
Farida | 2019-03-02 | coat | 15
```

Writing the code as :

```
select
     first_name, cast(o_date as date), sum(cost) over(partition by first_name) as tot 
from tab1
group by 
        1,2;
```

According to the query, first group by will be executed which will give:

```
Jill | 2019-04-01
Farida | 2019-03-01
Farida | 2019-03-02
```

and then we are squashing the rows by taking sum of cost column but for every partition of first_name.

I am expecting the output as

```
Jill | 2019-04-1 | 50
Farida | 2019-03-01 | 60
Farida | 2019-03-02 |60
```

The code is working fine without group by clause(which I already know how to do it). Why can't we use group by here? Please tell what causing the code to be incorrect?

Comment: The error message is very clear, what exactly do you not understand? You don't need to sum over a window here, you want the sum per group.

Comment: Hi Stu, I want sum of cost for each partition(first_name) not group

Comment: Defining a window function `over(partition by first_name)` after `group by 1`, eg grouping by first_name is useless. It would make more sense to partition by `category` instead of `first_name` in the window function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sum()` followed by an `OVER` clause is not an aggregation function though it has the same name as one.

That follows that `cost`, in your query, is neither an argument to an aggregation function nor in the `GROUP BY` clause.

But you can use a window (not "windows" by the way) function on the **result** of an aggregation function.

So the following is allowed. `sum()` is used as an aggregation function on `cost` first, and *then* the window function `sum()` is used on that.

```
SELECT first_name,
       cast(o_date AS date),
       sum(sum(cost)) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name) AS tot 
       FROM tab1
       GROUP BY first_name,
                cast(o_date AS date);
```

And as a side note: I recommend against using column ordinals in `GROUP BY` clauses. That's too easy to mess up. Prefer to use the column expressions instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sticky bit